# Mount failed on iso

Tags: mount, iso-image

I'm trying to install matlab, whose install file is a huge iso file.

However, when I try to mount it to a folder named matlab, it always fails with the following error:

```
mount: matlab: mount failed: No such file or directory.
```

The command I issued is(the result is the same with or without sudo and abs path):

```
mount -o loop ./R2023a_Linux.iso matlab
```

I have the iso file system compiled into my kernel.

How can I solve this?

Edit: File structure:

```
Downloads
 | some other files......
 | R2023a_Linux.iso
 | matlab (an empty directory)
```

which should be correct.

A strace log: [pastebin](https://bpa.st/FJEYK)

which has unexpected lines like this:

```
access(0x7f5bdf063ffc, F_OK)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Is matlab actually is in the same directory as the iso?

Comment: @TomYan The sad fact is, it is. I don't know why it can't find it, even if I feed the absolute path to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output message is misleading.

What was missing was not the matlab folder, but the loop block device itself.

Actually, removing the -o loop has the same strace results, which means mount automatically searches for loop when mounting iso files.

Compiling the kernel with loop support did the work for me.

Comment: alternatively you can use [fuseiso](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/FuseISO)

Answer (score 1):

I posit from the error message that "matlab" does not exist as a directory.  Try first creating the directory to mount the ISO and then using full paths - eg

```
  mkdir -p /path/to/mount/matlab
  mount -o loop /path/to/R2023a_Linux.iso /path/to/mount/matlab
```

Comment: I have created matlab as a directory in the same directory as the iso and ran the command inside the folder.